# time components if UTC and time zone is known

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date time picker, which uses `getHours`, `getMinutes`,.. to initialize the value. It works well if timezone coincide with user location, but I want to consider the case where user tz is different than the current browser locale setting. I can use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to correctly format the date into another timezone. But, I want to get the time component values (hour, minute,..) of say "America/Chicago" while my local time is "America/New_York". That is I need to get time as 17 if I set offset as "America/Chicago", irrespective of current local timezone . Is this possible without using moment.js, or any better way to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/zhvx6mmt/1/

```
const baseUTCDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 1, 23, 0, 0));
function formatDate(date, timeZone, locale) {
  const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', timeZoneName: 'short' };
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, Object.assign(options, {timeZone: timeZone})).format(date);
}

console.log(formatDate(baseUTCDate, "America/New_York",  'en-US')) 
// Wednesday, Mar 1, 2017, 6:00 PM EST

console.log(formatDate(baseUTCDate, "America/Chicago",  'en-US'))
// Wednesday, Mar 1, 2017, 5:00 PM CST

console.log(baseUTCDate.getHours()) // 18 - local time zone is EST
```

Comment: Weird that the first argument to *Intl* object methods is called "locale" when it's actually a language.

Comment: I too used locale and language interchangeably, and probably confused as well. thanks for pointing it out. Not sure why no API to get the time component!

Comment: worst case could always create a hashmap of all the available timezones and their offsets and do the math against Date.UTC

Comment: @charlietfl—using timezones like "America/Chicago" though means daylight saving changes are observed, whereas just setting the timezone offset (which isn't difficult) means working out such adjustments yourself.